# Docker-compose: Set a variable in env file and use it in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Docker and Docker-compose to build a stack of nginx+php.

I'm trying to set the timezone in my `.env` file and use it in a Dockerfile, but I might be missunderstanding something from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

**.env**

```
# Timezone
TIMEZONE=Europe/Madrid
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version '2'

services:
    php:
        build: php7-fpm
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH}:/var/www/app
            - ./logs:/var/www/logs
        environment:
            TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}

#[...more.stuff...]
```

**php7-fpm/Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
ARG TIMEZONE

#[...more.stuff...]

ENV TIMEZONE=${TIMEZONE}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TIMEZONE /etc/localtime && echo $TIMEZONE > /etc/timezone
RUN printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', $TIMEZONE > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini
```

The timezone is not set properly inside the container (running `php --info | grep timezone` inside the php container bash). If I write the zone manually in the Dockerfile, it works.

Comment: what is the actual problem here?

Comment: The timezone is not set properly inside the container.
If I write the zone manually in the Dockerfile, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the build argument in docker compose

```
version '2'

services:
    php:
        build: 
          dockerfile: php7-fpm
          args:
            TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH}:/var/www/app
            - ./logs:/var/www/logs
```

The `environment` are passed to the running container and not to the buildfile. For the you need to pass `args` in the `build` section

Comment: Yes, you can even pass those using `docker-compose`, see the compose file in my answer

Comment: i meant passing `--build-arg` at the `docker build` step, since he makes use of those before actually running the app (or at least that's how it looks to me)

Comment: With `build: php7-fpm` in the compose file. It means that `docker-compose` is building the image also

Comment: oh, missed that part. Thanks, i don't usually include a build step in my compose files

Comment: Clear now, thanks! By the way I think the parameter `environment` is not longer necessary.

Comment: @CarlosAS, yes that is true because the image would already have that