# Using env variables from docker compose in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I am confused, because it seems that an environment variable which is set in docker-compose.yml causes docker to rebuild my image on docker-compose up:

Dockerfile for apache_php_with_custom_docroot

```
FROM php:7.1.11-apache-jessie

# Set apache document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/web
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf
```

I'm building it with `docker build -t apache_php_with_custom_docroot .`

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:    
    image: apache_php_with_custom_docroot
    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/anotherfolder
```

So, the strange thing to me is: It works to set the APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT. When I run `docker-compose up -d` apache uses the docroot `/var/www/anotherfolder`.

I was sure, when my image was build, then I can't change it in my docker-compose file. I read something about `build` parameters e.g. here: [Docker-compose: Set a variable in env file and use it in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814441/docker-compose-set-a-variable-in-env-file-and-use-it-in-dockerfile)

But I did not set build params. How does docker know, that he has to rebuild my image? Where can I read about the principles behind this?

Comment: a bit rusty with docker! , as far as i know , every change in docker-compose.yml is need to make an up (because docker reads it and create the virtual filesystem and the container behavior), so i thing you need to attach this on the entrypoint , where you i.e can read a file with vars and load it every time containers start ...

Answer (score -1):

define a entry point in your dockerfile like:

```
ENTRYPOINT bash $APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT/entrypoint.sh
```

And then in your entry point every time containers starts, you will be able to read mapped volume with a file and inject in your container or declare the environments or related startup task you will need

```
enviroment=$(cat /mapped_config/enviroment.env)
if grep -Fxq "$enviroment" /home/.bashrc
  then 
      echo "Environment setted propertly"
  else
      echo "$enviroment" >> /home/.bashrc
      echo "enviorment setted!"
fi
```

It's just an idea , and probably not the best way , is how i deal it in past.

Comment: -1, because this is not an answer to my question. I do not understand why my code works, i did not search for an answer how this could be done in another way...

Comment: i just trying to explain  when you do docker-compose up, docker will read your docker-compose.yml file and build your image ( with config and vars you defined ), after if you will make any change on docker-compose file ( such as change env var etc..) you will need to build again ( not stop , start or restart ) if you wanna read something dynamically when containers starts you can do this staff in the entrypoint