# How to read .env file while building an image with Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

Here is my Docker file that is using by `docker-compose build` command:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libnewlib-arm-none-eabi avr-libc git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pip install cryptography

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r /code/misc/requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /static
RUN python /code/manage.py migrate
RUN python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Here is the service in `docker-compose.yml` that uses this `Dockerfile`:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  ...
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    command: bash -c "/code/run/gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/data/django/static
      - ./media:/data/django/media
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - misc/envs/.env
```

So, when I try to build this compose with `docker-compose build --no-cache` command it says that this environment variable is still undefined even if I try to explicityly add `RUN set -a && source /code/misc/envs/.env && set +a` step into `Dockerfile`

**UPD**

As a result my code running on last Dockerfile step

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
import os


def get_env_setting(setting, default=None):
    try:
        return os.environ[setting]
    except KeyError:
        if default is not None:
            return default
        error_msg = "Set the %s env variable" % setting
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SECRET_KEY = get_env_setting('SECRET_KEY')
```

gives me an error:

```
  File "/code/project/settings.py", line 34, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = get_env_setting('SECRET_KEY')
  File "/code/project/settings.py", line 22, in get_env_setting
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY env variable
```

Comment: what's the specific error you're getting?

Comment: updated question

Comment: adding the env_file to your Compose file should be enough, you don't need to take further steps in your Dockerfile. What is the format of your misc/envs/.env file? VAR=VALUE format works with no spaces.

Comment: This compose file from a working example uses an env file, maybe it helps: https://github.com/lvthillo/docker-php-postgres/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker-compose: Set a variable in env file and use it in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814441/docker-compose-set-a-variable-in-env-file-and-use-it-in-dockerfile)